# Word Tracked Changes - How to print markup without side panel?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to print a document to PDF in Word 2016.  The document has tracked changes turned on.  I want to print the document with the markup showing but without the panel that appears to the right side of the document showing the description of the changes.  Is that possible?  In my print preview it does not show that it will print the side panel but in the final document it is always there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Review there is a Comments check box. Clear the checkbox and try printing to PDF again.

Answer (score 0):

Save as html, open in a browser. It will contain comment balloons at the end of the text, not on the side. Print. This is the only way I have found after an hour of investigation.
Word 365, latest edition as of 2024.02.22

Answer (score 0):

for those that cannot find the Comments check box mentioned in https://superuser.com/a/1481619/1192744, here's how it's possible to not export the balloons to PDF in Office 2021. Go to the Review tab of the ribbon, and in the Tracking part of the ribbon, select "Simple Mark-up", and click on that little arrow thingy:

[image: tracking part of review tab of ribbon]

Then you'll get an options dialogue, where you can select which elements to show:

[image: track changes options]

Exporting a PDF now will have the simple mark-up only, without any balloons.